# Python Script to get list of all download links from an FTP based File Hosting URL

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I made a small script to get a list of all download links from an FTP based File Hosting URL. I have tested it on a couple of URLs and it works reasonably well.

Can you please point out mistakes and bad practices, suggest ways to improve, and if possible further generalize the code?

Also, please suggest ways I could use the Python Standard Library instead of Beautiful Soup without sacrificing too much simplicity, if possible.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

url = "http://some_ftp_url.net/movies/"

download_links = []
video_file_extensions = ('mkv', 'mp4', 'mpeg4', 'mov', 'avi')

def recursiveUrl(url, depth):
        if depth == 5:
                return url
        elif url.endswith(video_file_extensions):
                download_links.append(url)
                return
        else:
                page = requests.get(url)
                for link in BeautifulSoup(page.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'), features="html.parser"):
                        if (link.has_attr('href') and link.text != '../'):
                                recursiveUrl(url + link['href'], depth + 1)

def getLinks(url):
        page = requests.get(url)

        for link in BeautifulSoup(page.text, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'), features="html.parser"):
                if (link.has_attr('href') and link.text != '../'):
                        recursiveUrl(url + link['href'], 0)
        return download_links

if __name__ == '__main__':
        getLinks(url)
        for download_link in download_links:
                print('\n')
                print(download_link)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to stop using Beautiful Soup?

Comment: @AlexV Beautiful Soup is very handy. But I also wanted to know if there is another, feasibly straightforward, way of doing it using just the Python Standard Library. I'm not sure whether Beautiful Soup is a part of the Python Standard Library, but I'm guessing not.